# Clear all vertical auto layout constraints

Tags: ios, swift

I'm playing with auto layout a bit and I have button that simply pops over a list to select from. The problem is, I added a switch that lets me toggle off/on whether or not the searchBar should appear in the popover.

[image]
[image]
[image]

So I need to reset the table constraint between the top guide and the searchBar depending on the toggle.

I got it working with this code in the popover:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    if (searchBar.hidden) {
        let views = ["tableView": tableView]
        constraintsWithoutSearchbar = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[tableView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: views)
        self.view.removeConstraints(constraintsWithSearchbar)
        self.view.addConstraints(constraintsWithoutSearchbar)
    } else {
        let views = ["tableView": tableView, "searchBar": searchBar]
        constraintsWithSearchbar = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-10-[searchBar][tableView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: views)
        self.view.removeConstraints(constraintsWithoutSearchbar)
        self.view.addConstraints(constraintsWithSearchbar)
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

The problem is that I have to store off these constraints to remove them and add new ones or else I get **Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.** errors. I also get this error on the default auto generated constraint from IB as well.

Is there a way I can wipe all vertical constraints before new ones?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing -- storing the constraints in an ivar -- is just fine, maybe better than what you're asking for, since it gets only the constraints that you set.

You can, however, access "all vertical" constraints for a view using `UIView`'s [`constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis(_ axis: UILayoutConstraintAxis)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis:), passing `UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical`.